# Flexbox card is not filling remaining space

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I think that picture is self explanatory

[image]

I want those cards to fill remaining area. Somehow whatever I try it fails...

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header bg-primary text-light">
        Title
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="p-2">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">abc cba abc</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">cba abc cba</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-column">
                <div class="card p-2 flex-grow-1" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" *ngFor="let phraseByCategory of queries.phrasesByCategory">
                    <h5 class="card-title"> {{phraseByCategory.category}}</h5>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `flex-grow-1` inside flex container `d-flex` because `display: flex` affect only one 1 deep level.

> The display attribute only affects the direct rendering of a given element

[display docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/display)

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header bg-primary text-light">
        Title
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="p-2">  <!-- they are on same level -->
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">abc cba abc</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">cba abc cba</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-column flex-grow-1"> <!-- here -->  <!-- they are on same level -->
                <div class="card p-2" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" *ngFor="let phraseByCategory of queries.phrasesByCategory">
                    <h5 class="card-title"> {{phraseByCategory.category}}</h5>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Working example here**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hb4v4t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html